# Running two partially related cypher queries together

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to fetch two related collections from a Neo4j database.

The first one is to get some things that satisfy a list of conditions, something like this:

```sql
MATCH (n:Thing)
WHERE [complicated list of conditions]
RETURN n
ORDER BY n.label
LIMIT 25
```

the second one is to get nodes related to the nodes that satisfy the conditions, something like this:

```sql
MATCH (m:RelatedThing) -[:Relationship]-(n:Thing)
WHERE [same complicated conditions about n]
RETURN m
ORDER BY m.label 
LIMIT 25
```

Crucially, the m's don't have to be related to the first 25 n's that were returned by query 1.

It seems like there is a lot of repetition between these two queries. Is there a way to run them both in a single query?

Obviously this can be done in two queries, but reading around I haven't found a good way to run both queries together. It seems like maybe COLLECT could be useful, but it doesn't quite fit the use case.

EDIT: I am looking for a solution that works in version 3.5.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two [CALL subqueries](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/call-subquery/):

```
MATCH (n:Thing) WHERE < complicated list of conditions >
WITH COLLECT(n) AS list
CALL {
  WITH list
  UNWIND list AS x
  WITH x
  ORDER BY x.label LIMIT 25
  RETURN COLLECT(x) AS list1
}
CALL {
  WITH list
  UNWIND list AS y
  MATCH (m:RelatedThing)-[:Relationship]-(y)
  WITH DISTINCT m
  ORDER BY m.label LIMIT 25
  RETURN COLLECT(m) AS list2
}
RETURN list1, list2
```

##### For very old neo4j versions without CALL subquery

The APOC procedure `apoc.cypher.run` has been supported for a long time, and can be used instead of the more recent `CALL subquery` feature:

```
MATCH (n:Thing) WHERE < complicated list of conditions >
WITH COLLECT(n) AS list
CALL apoc.cypher.run("
  UNWIND list AS x
  WITH x
  ORDER BY x.label LIMIT 25
  RETURN COLLECT(x) AS list1",
  {list: list}
) YIELD value as val1
CALL apoc.cypher.run("
  UNWIND list AS y
  MATCH (m:RelatedThing)-[:Relationship]-(y)
  WITH DISTINCT m
  ORDER BY m.label LIMIT 25
  RETURN COLLECT(m) AS list2",
  {list: list}
 ) YIELD value as val2
RETURN val1.list1 AS list1, val2.list2 AS list2
```

Comment: This looks great but I am looking for a solution using version 3.5.12. I've updated the question

Comment: See the new addendum to my answer.